# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core cannot cast 'object' type to 'Tuple<T1, T2, T3>'

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) and trying to run a dynamic query with a model as below:

```
public class Index
{
    public long Position { get; set; }

    public object[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

And with a sample of data like this:

```
var indexes = new Dictionary<long, Index>();
indexes.Add(1, new Index { Position = 1000, Values = new object[3] { "Welly", "Chandra", Tuple.Create<int, int>(1, 2) } });
indexes.Add(2, new Index { Position = 1001, Values = new object[3] { "Darma", "Angelo", Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 4) } });
indexes.Add(3, new Index { Position = 1002, Values = new object[3] { "Abby", "Yeremia", Tuple.Create<int, int>(5, 6)} });
indexes.Add(4, new Index { Position = 1003, Values = new object[3] { "Yonathan", "Gunawan", Tuple.Create<int, int>(7, 8)} });
indexes.Add(5, new Index { Position = 1004, Values = new object[3] { "Aldy", "Santoso", Tuple.Create<int, int>(11, 12)} });
var queryable = indexes.Values.AsQueryable();
var result = queryable.Where("Values[1].Equals(\"Yeremia\") || ((Tuple<int, int>) Values[2]).Item2.Equals(8)").ToList();
```

But it always throw an exception:

```
Exception: No property or field 'Tuple' exists in ...
```

Is it not possible to use `type-casting` while querying here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you write string inside linq where clause.

Following is the completely working code at my end.

```
var indexes = new Dictionary<long, Index>();
            indexes.Add(1, new Index { Position = 1000, Values = new object[3] { "Welly", "Chandra", Tuple.Create<int, int>(1, 2) } });
            indexes.Add(2, new Index { Position = 1001, Values = new object[3] { "Darma", "Angelo", Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 4) } });
            indexes.Add(3, new Index { Position = 1002, Values = new object[3] { "Abby", "Yeremia", Tuple.Create<int, int>(5, 6) } });
            indexes.Add(4, new Index { Position = 1003, Values = new object[3] { "Yonathan", "Gunawan", Tuple.Create<int, int>(7, 8) } });
            indexes.Add(5, new Index { Position = 1004, Values = new object[3] { "Aldy", "Santoso", Tuple.Create<int, int>(11, 12) } });
            var queryable = indexes.Values.AsQueryable();
            var result = queryable.Where(cc=>cc.Values[1].Equals("Yeremia") || ((Tuple<int, int>) cc.Values[2]).Item2.Equals(8)).ToList();
```

UPDATE: This is working for me. Type conversion not required.

```
 var indexes = new Dictionary<long, Index>();
            indexes.Add(1, new Index { Position = 1000, Values = new object[3] { "Welly", "Chandra", Tuple.Create<int, int>(1, 2) } });
            indexes.Add(2, new Index { Position = 1001, Values = new object[3] { "Darma", "Angelo", Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 4) } });
            indexes.Add(3, new Index { Position = 1002, Values = new object[3] { "Abby", "Yeremia", Tuple.Create<int, int>(5, 6) } });
            indexes.Add(4, new Index { Position = 1003, Values = new object[3] { "Yonathan", "Gunawan", Tuple.Create<int, int>(7, 8) } });
            indexes.Add(5, new Index { Position = 1004, Values = new object[3] { "Aldy", "Santoso", Tuple.Create<int, int>(11, 12) } });
            var queryable = indexes.Values.AsQueryable();
            var result = queryable.Where("Values[1].Equals(\"Yeremia\") || Values[2].Item2.Equals(8)").ToList();
```

Comment: Because I make a dynamic SQL-like query string builder in my backend, so I need to construct a String as the Where(...) parameter

Comment: If you are using linq then you have to work on expression to make dynamic query. Also if above code compile in your machine it means that you are using something else that you have not mention in your code.

Comment: Yes, I use https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core library, as mentioned in the question's title as `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`.

Comment: It throws `Exception: Target object is not an ExpandoObject` here